# Conditional if evaluation with &&

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

So we have:

```
if (arguments.length != 1 && arguments.length != 2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of arguments in " + string);
}
```

If `arguments` is of length 1 it passes this if block but `why`. The evaluation should work after my knowledge like this:

> if (args != 1  == true) AND (args != 2 == true)

Meaning `args.length = [0, 3, 4, ...]` should be only valid valid to pass. But it skipps the `if` even if it is with `args.legth == 1`.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem that it should be

```
  if (arguments.length == 1 || arguments.length == 2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of arguments in " + string);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow anything except for 1 or 2, use this:

```
if (args.length == 1 || args.length == 2) {
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of arguments in " + string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if arguments is of length 1 it passes this if block but why. The
>   evaluation should work after my knowledge like this:
>
> if (args != 1  == true) AND (args != 2 == true)

This doen't make much sense. If `args.length` is 1 then `args.length != 1` is false, not true.